# PHP - Output array value that contains a specific text marker

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, string, shopify

I'm using a function to output a collection of products in Shopify, onto a WordPress page.

I've got most of the data displaying correctly, except a custom value that is entered as a tag in Shopify. Using the api, I'm then trying to get this specific tag for the product subtitle which is formatted with att:Subtitle: before each product custom value/text.

This is the code I have got to (I've commented other unsuccessful attempts in the middle) - this is inside the overall code to show the 4 products in the Shopify collection:

```
 // Using tags to output custom data from products
$tags = $current_product['tags'];

// $tags is a string, this turns the values into an array
$product_tags = explode(',', $tags);

// Evaluate if there is a string with att:Subtitle in the product tags
// https://tecadmin.net/check-string-contains-substring-in-php/
$subtitle_attribute_key = "att:Subtitle:";

if (strpos($tags, 'att:Subtitle:') !== false) {  
    // Returns a numbered value corresponding to my subtitle attribute
    // $key = array_search($subtitle_attribute_key, $product_tags);
    $sub = strpos($tags, $subtitle_attribute_key);

    // Turns the numbered value into a text value
    // $numArray = explode(" ", $sub);
    // var_dump($numArray);
    $value = print_r($sub, true);
    // $value = array_search("att:Subtitle:",$product_tabs);
    // $value = array_search("att:Subtitle:", $tabs); // Warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given
    // $result = $product_tags['$value']; // my attempt to return the text

    // Remove att:Subtittle: in front of the subtitle value to output the clean final value
    $subtitle = ltrim($value, 'att:Subtitle:');
}
```

So far it comes out as a number value where I'm displaying $subtitle... but I can't figure out how to display the custom text value instead.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT: I am working with products that have multiple tags and I do not control these. Out of the tags I'm trying to find the one that starts with att:Subtitle: but only show the custom value after that marker.

When I echo $tags, the ist comes out something like this:

```
att:Benefit:balance, att:Perfect:Combination Skin, att:Size: 1.8 oz, att:Subtitle: Multi-Tasking Product, Key Ingredient 1, Key Ingredient 2, Essentials, meta-related-product-xyz, meta-related-product-brandname
```

They will all have a different list of tags

Comment: Hello. Can you include what `$tags` displays in your post? That is can you `echo $tags` and include that text in your post above? ... Btw `strpos()` returns a numeric value of where the sentinel (needle)  was first found in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course it comes out as a number. You're getting a number from the `strpos()` and ultimate trying to run `ltrim()` on it.

If you're expecting the desired text to be in `$tags` immediately following 'att:Subtitle:' and have nothing else in that string, `$subtitle = substr($tags, strpos('att:Subtitle:') + strlen('att:Subtitle:'));` should give it to you. If you're expecting it to possibly be an element in the `$product_tags` array, need to loop (I'm assuming it shows up once, at most):

```
foreach ($product_tags as $product_tag) {
    if (strpos($product_tag, 'att:Subtitle:') !== false) { 
        $subtitle = substr($product_tag, strpos($product_tag, 'att:Subtitle:') + strlen('att:Subtitle:'));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks belltouche ! I understand my approach was frustrating - I tried to do this but I do not know how so I am aware there's something that makes no sense in my code. I was just trying to do this every way I could before asking for help. - Your code returns text but not wat I'm after. It's somehow returning another tag as there are many tags in the tags field. Unfortunately I cannot control the content in the tags.

Comment: I algo get this error message: Warning: strpos() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: This code 'foreach ($product_tags as $product_tag) {
    if (strpos($tags, 'att:Subtitle:') !== false) { 
        $subtitle = substr($product_tag, strpos($product_tag,'att:Subtitle:') + strlen($result));
        break;
    }
}' seems to return whichever tag is the first in the tags list correctly @beltouche - I wonder if there's a way to target the specific att:Subtitle tag wherever it is in the list?

Comment: I realized there was an error in my loop code. It now checks each element in the `$product_tags` array, and returns information from the first one it finds with 'att:Subtitle:' in it.

Comment: Great. I'm going to edit the title of the post so it more closely matches what you needed answered.

Answer (score 0):

So for what I understand you're trying to get rid of 'att:Subtitle:' from the tags on your products descriptions? maybe you should try replacing that value on your tags array

```
// Using tags to output custom data from products
$tags = $current_product['tags'];

// $tags is a string, this turns the values into an array
$product_tags = explode(',', $tags);

// Get rid of attribute on product tag
for($i = 0; $i < count($product_tags); $i++){
    $subtitle = str_replace(':att:Subtitle','',$product_tags[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rubens - actually it's a list of tags I don't control, that is different on every product in the collection and I need to show the tag that starts with att:Subtitle: without showing that first part of it.